# Is it possible to seed data from Configuration file, into a table that has been changed due to plural and single spelling difference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

I am currently setting up the seeding data from the configuration file, but come across the plural and single name change of a table. (Category/Categories).

The seed method works fine for all other tables except for Categories, which I assume is to do with the difference of property name (Category) and Actual table name it creates (Categories)

Database Context:

```
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext(): base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Configuration:

```
 var test = new Category { CategoryName = "test" }; --- This cant find CategoryName despite the property being in the model.

            context.Categories.Add(test);


            context.SaveChanges();
```

It seems like a simple misunderstanding between model and table but I cant figure out how to map, is this possible without having to change table name?

Edit:
This is the Category Model:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of `Category`?

Comment: I have added the model class in the edit, tia.

Comment: Are you sure that `var test = new Category` is about `WebApplication1.Models.Category` and not a `Category` in another namespace?

Comment: Thank you @GertArnold, I assumed it was looking within the models section. I added var test = new WebApplication1.Models.Category { CategoryName = "test" }; and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Gert Arnold. The Category I was trying to get was a different namespace.